# A branch in a github repo showing as not-merged

Tags: git

Suppose I've a master and a feature branch.

Suppose that I've made a few commits in the feature branch and no commits in master.

Now when I checkout master and issue the command

```
git merge --squash feature
```

and then remove the branch using

```
git branch -d feature
```

It asks me to use the -D to remove it, but why does it do that ? hasn't the branch already been merged with master ? If it has been merged, then why does it ask to force delete a branch ?

Answer (score 0):

I think one reason could be that squash actually stages all the commits of the feature branch into master and you have to manually do a

```
 git commit -m"Merged feature branch"
```

So a --squash merge does not generate new commit like a recursive merge, nor is it a fast forward merge, I think git internally checks the ref-id's and thats why it reports that feature has not been merged with master as it cannot see the commits of feature branch on masters history.